# If $g: Y \to Z$ is a continuous injection, then a map $f : X \to Y$ is open if $g\circ f$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $g: Y \to Z$ is a continuous injection, then a map $f : X \to Y$ is open if $g\circ f$ is open.

To show the map $f : X \to Y$ is open, we first take any open subset $U$ from $X$ and then show that $f(U)$ is open. But I am unable to do this. Not able to understand to use the fact that $g\circ f$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $g$ is injective implies that for an open $U\subset X$ we have$$f(U)=g^{-1}(g(f(U)))=g^{-1}(g\circ f(U)),$$and the claim follows from $g\circ f$ being open and $g$ being continuous. Note that the above equation does *not* hold for a general $g$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $g \circ f$ is open, so for your open set $U \subseteq X$ we known that $V = g[f[U]]$ is open. We need $f[U]$ to be open.

Show that $g^{-1}[V] = g^{-1}[g[f[U]] = f[U]$ because $g$ is injective.

It then follows using continuity of $g$ that $f[U]$ is open in $Y$.